# how to accept part of variable(string) as dynamic value in cobol?

Tags: sql, db2, cobol, mainframe

I have a field in working storage section WS_CONTRACT_NUM , this has few hard-coded values of leght 15 characters.But first 5 characters could be anything, my question is how can i declare this variable in that case.

```
WORKING STORAGE
 01 WS_CONTRACT_NUM PIC X(15) VALUE '?????9999999999' --- > instead of '?' what can i give so that dynamic value can be substituted in my query.
```

And i am performing select query like this :

```
EXEC SQL
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONTRACT_NUM = :WS_CONTRACT_NUM
END-EXEC
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `SELECT *` is a bad practice.  If a column is added to the table your code will break.  Always explicitly select the columns you need, and only the columns you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for SQL LIKE, see [IBM docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_likepredicate.html), where

> The underscore character (_) represents any single character.
>   The percent sign (%) represents a string of zero or more characters.

To use this in COBOL you'd either

```
MOVE '_____9999999999' TO WS_CONTRACT_NUM 
EXEC SQL
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONTRACT_NUM LIKE :WS_CONTRACT_NUM
END-EXEC
```

or (less likely that you want to do it)

```
EXEC SQL
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONTRACT_NUM LIKE '%9999999999'
END-EXEC
```

or maybe (I have no option to tests this, please report back)

```
MOVE '%9999999999' TO WS_CONTRACT_NUM
*> this may search for the trailing spaces,
*> if it does define a smaller variable
EXEC SQL
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE CONTRACT_NUM LIKE :WS_CONTRACT_NUM
END-EXEC
```

Answer (score 0):

PIC X is the any character symbol.  So `PIC X(5)9(10)`.

Unless you need to do arithmetic, you could get away with `PIC X(15)`.    Just because something is called "Number" doesn't mean it has to be stored as computational. It is more often than not more efficient to store fields called "Number" as character data. For instance Social Insurance Number - rarely do you have to add 1 or divide by 2, so you can get away with treating the field as PIC X.

Or to add clarity in this case:

```
01 ws-contract-value.
   05 first-part pic x(5).
   05 contract-number pic 9(10).   *> or x(10) unless you need to do math
```

If you need to verify that the character data is all digits, you can use `IF field IS NUMERIC ...` for validation of PIC X fields.

Comment: i understood the part of using PIC X to declare  the field .But , my filed values are hard-coded within working storage (there are 16 values for 1 contract_num) . Also i need these values inside SQL query as mentioned in my question, which will hit my db2 table .